Flutter WebView tries to load the link: https://www.whatsapp.com/download but ends up on a page "about:blank"
Flutter WebView tries to load the link: https://www.whatsapp.com/download but ends up on a page "about:blank".
But if I try to debug using breakpoints, the navigation of WebView successfully goes to https://www.whatsapp.com/download
It seems that there is some multithreading concurrency issue that I can't understand.
I have this issue on iPhone simulator without Whatsapp installed, and on real iPhone 12 mini (iOS 17.4.1).
Code:
class _MyWebViewScreenState
    extends State<MyWebViewScreen> {
  var _controller = WebViewController();
  var loadingPercentage = 0;
  final Environment _env;
  
  // Some other lines of code

  _MyWebViewScreenState({Environment? env})
      : _env = env ?? Environment();

  void _initController() {
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
            log(' Web View Progress Percentage $progress');
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = progress;
            });
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            log(' Web View Started Loading Page "$url"');
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 0;
            });
            if (readyToReload) {
              readyToReload = false;
            }
          },
          onUrlChange: handleLoginRedirect,
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            log('✅ Web View Finished Loading Page "$url"');
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 100;
            });
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            log('❌ Web View Error "$error"');
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 0;
            });
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            var url = request.url;
            log('➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "$url"');
            if (request.isMainFrame) {
              log("isMainFrame == true");
            } else {
              log("isMainFrame == false");
            }
            if (request.url == "about:blank") {
              log("request.url == 'about:blank'");
            }
            if (_isExternalScheme(request.url)) {
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.url);
              _launchUrl(uri);
              log("NavigationDecision.prevent");
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            log("NavigationDecision.navigate");
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.viewModel.initialUrl),
          headers: _headers() ?? {});
  }

  bool _isExternalScheme(String url) {
    // Regex to match any scheme that ends with a colon and is not http(s)
    final regex =
        RegExp(r'^(?!https?:)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:)(\/\/)?', caseSensitive: false);
    return regex.hasMatch(url);
  }

  Future<void> _launchUrl(Uri url) async {
    try {
      log('await launchUrl("$url")');
      await launchUrl(url);
    } catch (error) {
      log('Error: $error');
      // Ignoring
    }
  }

Log:
[log]  Web View Progress Percentage 10
[log] ➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "https://wa.me/1234567890"
[log] isMainFrame == true
[log] NavigationDecision.navigate
[log] ➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "https://wa.me/1234567890"
[log] isMainFrame == true
[log] NavigationDecision.navigate
[log]  Web View Started Loading Page "https://wa.me/1234567890"
[log] ➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0"
[log] isMainFrame == true
[log] NavigationDecision.navigate
[log]  Web View Progress Percentage 30
[log] ➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "whatsapp://send/?phone=1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0"
[log] isMainFrame == true
[log] await launchUrl("whatsapp://send/?phone=1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0")
[log] NavigationDecision.prevent
[log]  Web View Progress Percentage 100
[log] ✅ Web View Finished Loading Page "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0"

============================
Whatsapp landing page loaded
============================

-------------------------
Tap on "Continue to chat"
-------------------------

[log] ➡️ onNavigationRequest url: "https://www.whatsapp.com/download"
[log] isMainFrame == true
[log] NavigationDecision.navigate
[log]  Web View Progress Percentage 10
[log]  Web View Started Loading Page ""
[log]  Web View Progress Percentage 100
[log] ✅ Web View Finished Loading Page "about:blank"

pubspec.yaml:
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.1
  webview_cookie_manager: ^2.0.6
.......

P.S. I tried to update webview_flutter package to 4.7.0 but it doesn't help.
